# google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How do i add a custom control to google maps v3 with jquery?

Comment: What kind of control? More details please...

Comment: like the map type select control, i want to use my own controls for that.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to be sure to bind the custom control's elements to the functions you want them to perform on the map itself, but to add a custom control using jQuery to manipulate the DOM, do something like the following:

```
$(function () {
    var myOptions = {
        ...

        mapTypeControl: false
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map($mapDiv, myOptions);

    ...


    // Remove the custom control from the DOM to memory
    $control = $(".myControlSelector").detach();

    // Push the control to the top right position on the map
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push($control[0]);
});
```

More documentation is located here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var $control` ?

Answer (score 1):

One example adds a tag filtering control using [jQuery Google Maps plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/), see "[Filter Markers Example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html)" near bottom.

Android App using same jQuery plugin with similar example [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mds.gmapdemo) (source available, phone/tablet/desktop).